Add-In for .NET is crashing when calculation mode is not automatic
I have a custom addin for .NET, that is requesting data from an API and is printing the result on the excel working sheet.
It works as expected when running it on automatic calculation, but when I change it to manual or to Partial it starts to crash the excel app.
On logs, it seems to print well the information on the working sheet, but some error is appearing on the ok button. The okay button is only responsible to call the f
Will leave the button ok code, some related functions and logs:
private async void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
                

                helperClass.fromHistorical = true;
        helperClass.origin = false;

        List<string> countriesList = new List<string>();
        List<string> indicatorsList = new List<string>();

        foreach (string item in selectedCountryLstBx.Items) countriesList.Add(item);
        foreach (string item in selectedIndicatorLstBx.Items) indicatorsList.Add(item);

        string countries = string.Join(",", countriesList);
        string indicators = string.Join(",", indicatorsList);



        helperClass.runFormula = "RunAutomatically = 1";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range dateCell = helperClass.CellAddress(activeCellPositionBox.Text);

        string formula = "";

        log.Warn("countries: " + countries);
        log.Warn("indicators: " + indicators);

        formula = string.Format("=NewHistorical( \"{0}\", \"{1}\",, {4})",
                countries,
                indicators,
        dateCell[2, 2].Address[false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1]);


        TERibbon.cellRange.Formula = formula;            
        Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error("Message => " + ex.Message);
        log.Error("Source => " + ex.Source);
        log.Error("StackTrace => " + ex.StackTrace.ToString());

        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.");
    }

    
}


private void header_to_excel()
{
  log.Trace("header_to_excel() - printTSData");
  try
    {
     var writeRange = _currentWorksheet.Range[
                   (Range)_currentWorksheet.Cells[_dataStartCell.Row, _dataStartCell.Column + 1],                        (Range)_currentWorksheet.Cells[_dataStartCell.Row, _dataStartCell.Column + _names.Length]];
                writeRange.Value2 = _names.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      log.Info(ex.Message);
      log.Trace(ex.StackTrace);
      throw;
   }            
  }

public void PopulateData()
{
    log.Trace("PopulateData() - printTSData");

    try
    {
        DataWriteMutex.WaitOne();

        header_to_excel();

        Range endCell = _currentWorksheet.Cells[_dataStartCell.Row + _dict.Count, _dataStartCell.Column + _names.Length];
        formulaColumns frmlaColumnsPair2 = new formulaColumns(_newFormula, String.Join(",", _names),
            _currentWorksheet.Range[_dataStartCell, endCell], 
            _formulaCell);
        TheRibbon.myFormulasDict[_formulaCell.Address[false, false]] = frmlaColumnsPair2;
        
        if (TheRibbon.myMainDict.ContainsKey(TheRibbon.sheet.Index.ToString()))
        {
            TheRibbon.myMainDict[TheRibbon.sheet.Index.ToString()] = TheRibbon.myFormulasDict;
        }
        else
        {
            TheRibbon.myMainDict.Add(TheRibbon.sheet.Index.ToString(), TheRibbon.myFormulasDict);
        }

        DataWriteMutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }
    catch (COMException e)
    {
        log.Warn("PopulateData() - printTSData - again");
        log.Info(e.Message);
        log.Trace(e.StackTrace);

        Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);                
        DataWriteMutex.ReleaseMutex();
        if (e.HResult == -2147417846 || e.HResult == -2146777998)
        {
            PopulateData();
            return;
        }
        throw;
    }

    try
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(TheRibbon.sheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(TheRibbon.app);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        return;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex);
        return;
    }
}

Logs:
2024-08-21 09:00:11.7764 TRACE TE.printTSData.PopulateData PopulateData() - printTSData
2024-08-21 09:00:11.7764 TRACE TE.printTSData.header_to_excel header_to_excel() - printTSData
2024-08-21 09:00:11.7887 DEBUG TE.TEUDF.customFunctionEnd customFunctionEnd()
2024-08-21 09:00:11.7887 TRACE TE.TEUDF.customFunctionEnd TS
2024-08-21 09:00:11.7887 TRACE TE.sharedFunctions.getAnswer getAnswer() - Updated at 09:00:11

2024-08-21 09:00:11.7887 ERROR TE.historicalFrm.btnOK_Click Message => Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
2024-08-21 09:00:11.7887 ERROR TE.historicalFrm.btnOK_Click Source => mscorlib
2024-08-21 09:00:11.7887 ERROR TE.historicalFrm.btnOK_Click StackTrace =>    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Formula(Object )
   at TE.historicalFrm.<btnOK_Click>d__46.MoveNext()

Tried to change the calculation mode programmatically and tried to use .Calculate() when calculation mode is not automatic, but with no results
